Python 2.7: set up windows station for process to hide popup windows
I have a code like:
command = [<some exe>, <flags>, <arguments>]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, cwd=self.dirpath, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

When I run this code and my exe gets executed I can see popup windows of this exe on my screen which is ok. But are there any ways to hide popup windows?
I am thinking of setting up window station different to WinSta0 like so:
import win32service
OpenWindowStation('<another win sta>', True, 0x37F).SetProcessWindowStation()

and then run Popen to execute the command.
But I dont understand which window station to use.
Probably there are any other ways to do what I want.
